# Как сохранить команду для терминала?

Tags: macos, mac

Часто пользуюсь определенными командами в терминале. Можно ли их сохранить в короткий алиас, чтобы не вводить всю команду?

Например, хочу вместо `ssh user@11.22.33.44 -p 1234` использовать команду `serv1`

Моя ось - Mac OS

Comment: вроде [как-то так](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-creating-aliases-for-commands-1305638)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создаем в домашней директории файл `.bash_aliases` , в той же директории, в файл `.bash_profile` добавляем код:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Теперь можно в .bash_aliases добавлять свои алиасы в формате:

```
alias serv1='ssh user@11.22.33.44 -p 1234'
```

Каждый алиас с новой строки.

Comment: спасибо, великолепно!